# DataSet Group By with Expression Tree

Tags: c#, lambda, group-by, dataset, expression-trees

I'm trying to convert the following lambda expression into an Expression tree

```
var datatable = "<DataTable retrieved and filled with SQLCommand>"
var aggregate = datatable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x =>
                            new {
                                MeasureCode = x.Field<string>("CODMEASURE"),
                                FieldName = x.Field<string>("FIELDNAME"),
                                Formula = x.Field<string>("FORMULA"),
                                TableCode = x.Field<string>("CODTAB")})
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                Organization = String.Join(",",x.Select(z=>z.CODDIV)),
                                x.Key.MeasureCode,
                                x.Key.FieldName,
                                x.Key.Formula,
                                x.Key.TableCode
                            });
```

and thanks to various articles I've been able to write the following code that performs the first group by

```
.GroupBy(x =>
                            new {
                                MeasureCode = x.Field<string>("CODMEASURE"),
                                FieldName = x.Field<string>("FIELDNAME"),
                                Formula = x.Field<string>("FORMULA"),
                                TableCode = x.Field<string>("CODTAB")})
```

Below the code that builds the expression tree:

**1. Declare the "x" input parameter**

```
            var dataRowParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow), "x");
            var dataRowType = typeof(DataRow);
```

**2. Create an anonymous type with one property for each datatable columns using the TypeBuilder class**

```
            Dictionary<string, Expression> GroupByFields = new Dictionary<string, Expression>();

            var helper = new ReflectionHelper();
            var myTypeBuilder = helper.GetTypeBuilder();

            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                if (column.ColumnName.Equals("CODDIV")) continue;


                // Add the column as dynamic object property
                myTypeBuilder.DefineField(column.ColumnName, column.DataType, FieldAttributes.Public);
```

**3. While looping through the columns I also create the Expression for accessing the DataRow's Field method like x.Field("columnName")**

```
                // Get the expression for dynamically call the DataRow field method
                MethodInfo mi = typeof(DataRowExtensions).GetMethod("Field", new Type[] { typeof(DataRow), typeof(string) });
                mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(column.DataType);
                var columnName = Expression.Constant(column.ColumnName, typeof(string));
                var valueGetter = Expression.Call(mi, new Expression[] { dataRowParameter, columnName });
                //Add method definition to the list of fields
                GroupByFields.Add(column.ColumnName, valueGetter);
            }


            // Create the type and assign it to a "new" expression
            var dynamicType = myTypeBuilder.CreateType();
```

**4. When I get all the columns, I create the association between the anonymous type property and the DataRowField**

```
            var bindingArray = dynamicType.GetFields()
                                .Select(p => Expression.Bind(p, GroupByFields[p.Name]))
                                .OfType<MemberBinding>()
                                .ToArray();
            var GroupedRow = Expression.New(dynamicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
            var memberInit = Expression.Convert(Expression.MemberInit(GroupedRow, bindingArray),typeof(object));

            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<DataRow, object>>(memberInit, dataRowParameter);
```

**5. Then to test the result I do the GroupBy using lambda from my Expression tree and one written as normal lambda expression.**

```
            var groupByResult = table.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().GroupBy(predicate);

            var aggregate = table.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().GroupBy(x =>
                        new
                        {
                            MeasureCode = x.Field<string>("CODMEASURE")
                        });
            /*.Select(x => new
            {
                Organization = String.Join(",",x.Select(z=>z.Field<string>("CODDIV"))),
            });*/
```

**6. The correctResult is the count from the groupby using the LINQ Lambda Expression and is giving the right result, the result variable instead is returning the wrong result the is simply all the record without grouping**

```
            var correctresult = aggregate.ToArray().Count();
            var result = groupByResult.ToArray().Count();
            return table;
```

I've tried to use the debug view to understand the difference between the two lambda but i see only a small difference.

The one returning the correct result is

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy(
    .Constant<System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[System.Data.DataRow]>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Data.DataRow]),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Data.DataRow,<>f__AnonymousType2`4[System.String]]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Data.DataRow,<>f__AnonymousType2`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]>(System.Data.DataRow $x)
{
    .New <>f__AnonymousType2`4[System.String](
        .Call System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field(
            $x,
            "CODMEASURE"),
        )
}
```

The one NOT GROUPING is

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy(
    .Constant<System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[System.Data.DataRow]>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Data.DataRow]),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Data.DataRow,System.Object]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Data.DataRow,System.Object]>(System.Data.DataRow $x) {
    (System.Object).New 13d459a0-b85d-4c0d-8ab1-8f0e9af36ad7(){
        CODMEASURE = .Call System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field(
            $x,
            "CODMEASURE")
    }
}
```

So I suppose that the reason for which is not grouping is because the one built with expression tree is using a System.Object instead of an anonymous type with the right properties mapped

But I don't know how to make it using an anomymous type, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "the following lambda expression", which one do you mean? You have two lambda expressions (parameter to `GroupBy` and parameter to `Select`) or did you intend to create the entire assignment to `aggregate`?

Comment: Hi, my goal is create the entire assignment to aggregate, but till now I wrote the code to create just the one related to .GroupBy